# How to detect repetitive patterns in questionnaire answers

Tags: survey, pattern-recognition

I am dealing with the question how to detect repetitive patterns in questionnaire answers. The idea is to filter out cases with clear patterns like

`1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,1,2,3,...` or `4,9,4,9,4,9,4,8,4,9,...` or `5,5,5,5,5,5,2,5,5,5,5,...`

I am not sure which topic this is. Signal detection? Pattern recognition? Any hint would be great :-)

P.s. A quick method using R would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

The patterns you mentioned can be discovered with a an array shift.

Using `python` notations, for example:

```
[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
```

Is the same if we cut 2 items from the left and paste them to the right.

Lets denote pattern length (2 in the example) as $l$

```
def similarity(arr,l):
    """Returns the percentage of the array that is matched with the pattern"""
    rotated=[arr[l:]+arr[:l]]
    identical_entries=len([1 for a,r in zip(arr,rotated) if a==r])
    return float(identical_entries)/len(arr)
```

The function above returns the percentage of items that follow a pattern of size $l$

Now, all we have left is the check several pattern sizes

```
for l in range(10):
   print ("For size {}, the similarity is {}".format(l,similarity(arr,l)))
```

Comment: Hi uri, and thanks fo the idea. Indeed that could be an approach. The idea is not to need a given pattern as you suggest because then you have to test a lot of patterns giving a questionnaire of 54 questions with 5 choices. At the moment I am testing an approach to calculate entropy.

Comment: Note that this code doesn't test if given pattern repeats, it tests weather a pattern of a certain **length** repeats

Comment: But then you could also compare the maximum of unique answers with the maximum uniq answers of the pattern. Anyway I just realized that there is a bias towards the mean so both approaches are affected by this bias I guess.

Comment: And there is also the shannon-index that calculates the diversity